# Memory ordering. Two processors.

Tags: memory, x86, intel

[image]

This example comes from 64-IA-32 Architectures Software Developers Manual.

[image]
And I cannot understand why store of CPU #0 must be visible for other processors? In that concrete example ( when r1 = 1, r2 = 1) I agree that it is obvious that store made by CPU #0 must be retired firstly- I mean the 1 value must be in memory/cache in fact ( not in store buffer).

But what about general case? Is it possible the following situation:

CPU#0 stored: `mov [_x], 1` but it was stored in CPU#0's `store buffer`, and then CPU#1 loaded: `mov r1, [_x]` and in fact, `r1` is equal to 0?

Comment: Memory is shared by all processor cores so what cpu #0 writes is visible to cpu #1.  Memory sharing is in fact what this is all about.

Comment: See http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ for a thorough explanation of a case like this, with real code that demonstrates reordering happening in practice.

Comment: BTW, the phrase you're looking for is "globally visible", not "retired".  Loads become globally visible much earlier than retirement.  It does happen to be the case that stores become globally visible (and are committed to L1 cache) on retirement.