# Busy loop and the barrier

Tags: x86, operating-system, barrier

```
void loop(int loops) 
    {
      while (loops-- > 0)
        asm volatile ("" : : : "memory")
    }
```

1. I know that `asm volatile ("" : : : "memory")` prevents the compiler reorder instruction. But, here, I cannot see what can be reordered and why it could be problematic in terms of concurrency. ( I take into account possible interrupts). So, why is there a barrier?
2. And second, the connected issue. 
   Let's assume that we have a 10000000 line piece of code ( see below). As we know the CPU can reorder a StoreLoad.

   mov [eax], $2;
   nop;
   nop;
   ...;
   nop;
   mov ebx, [ecx];

How deeply does the CPU is able to predict that there is a chance to apply StoreLoad?

The same question can be applied to the compiler, but it concerns various reordering ( not only StoreLoad and not only memory operations )

Comment: 1) Perhaps as a side effect it prevents the optimizer from discarding the otherwise "unnecessary" modification of 'loops.'

Comment: What happens if you take it out and compile the function with `-O3`?  How is the code different from with the barrier in place?

Comment: I see. Therefore, do you suggest that there is barrier because, otherwise, it would be removed by the compiler? What about the 2. question? Perhaps, I didn't explain well what I meant?

Comment: I have no thoughts on #2.  But yes, without the memory clobber, it could completely remove the "time waster" loop.  This is a bad way to do delays.  If you wanted to replace it, perhaps something like __builtin_ia32_pause()?

Comment: I didn't get notified of your reply, since you didn't use `@peter`.
Just to clarify, you're saying this is existing code that someone else wrote?  From that teaching OS that you're looking at?  That wasn't obvious, especially with the missing semicolon that means it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL:DR**: The problem here is that you're only thinking about it as `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`, but that's not the only thing GNU C `volatile asm` statements do.

---

Yes, obviously the barrier is there to make a nasty busy-wait delay loop.  Remember that a volatile `asm` statement can't be reordered with any other C statements, not just memory operations.

[Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',sourcez:G4ewlgJgBANiIAcD6A7EBDAzgWwBRhQBdZ4FMBKKAKAG8qooB3ACzBgFMpc5FMBaPlAB8UAAyU6DBgHppWbFFAx0hNp1wAiDVABcu/RuztsIAE4BPDeQDc9KAF8qjqlVlRT7dKdPoUAc3ZoADMzKEwwbAQOUyh5KlBIEkRUECNsAGM4ACMs9lN8IiSyCTsIEChJKXlFEGVVDi4tfT09aQAqKENjM0soNukoGzt7JlYG3AEeMmExIecE6CmkLK9TMDyC4imKakqWNS5tgRnxCrsGaqUVA81tFoM0nqtbBkdHIAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
void loop_nomemclobber(int loops) {
  do {     // loop rearranged for simpler asm
    asm volatile ("" : : : /* "memory" */ );
  } while (--loops > 0);
}

loop_nomemclobber:
.L3:
    sub     edi, 1
    test    edi, edi
    jg      .L3
    ret
```

We still get a loop even without forcing all reachable memory to be up-to-date and treated as clobbered.  So the reason the `asm volatile` statement does this has nothing to do with the `"memory"` clobber.

`int loops` is a local with automatic storage.  The compiler can prove that nothing (including the asm statement) has any way to determine where it might be in memory, so it doesn't have to be in memory at all.

---

> How deeply does the CPU is able to predict that there is a chance to apply StoreLoad?

The CPU doesn't go looking for chances to reorder memory for no reason!  Reordering happens naturally (unless prevented with MFENCE) because the CPU needs to buffer stores until it's certain that they're not speculative, and on cache-miss stores.  So it puts stores in the Store Buffer, and they eventually commit to cache.

There isn't a little demon inside the CPU saying "aha, here's another chance to make things difficult for Gilgamesz, maybe I'll really trick him this time with this reordering!"

---

There is a real question here, and that's **how far apart two instructions need to be (in time, or in number of insns, or number of intervening loads/stores) before a specific microarchitecture doesn't have enough out-of-order resources for that store to ever be buffered until after that load.**

I don't know, but since StoreStore reordering isn't allowed, a cache-miss store to a highly-contended cache line can't sit there waiting to gain access to the cache line while millions of other instructions run.  Unless none of those instructions were a store.

I don't know the answer, but I think it's plausible that a store could theoretically be delayed for millions of cycles on Intel Haswell, maybe bounded only by the fairness algorithms of the hardware arbitration mechanisms that handle the case where multiple cores contend for access to the same cache line.

I forget what I've read about whether modern Intel hardware works this way or not, but I think maybe a store can retire from the out-of-order core but still not have committed to L1 cache.  Instead, it's only in the store queue as a store that will definitely happen.  That would let cache-miss stores avoid blocking new instructions from entering the ROB.  (Loads need to probe the store buffer to preserve correct execution within the single core, but doing that doesn't require the stores to also be tracked by the ROB).

Comment: The entire asm statement could have been simplified to `asm("");`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh, haha.  Yes, because `asm()` with no outputs is implicitly volatile.

Comment: "Even without that, the compiler has to assume that the asm volatile statement might read any globals" Actually, it doesn't.  Accessing (non-volatile) globals from within gcc's extended asm (without explicitly listing them as inputs) is unsafe.  Up until gcc v7.x, this wasn't safe in basic asm either.  That said, in this particular case it works out that way, since using asm typically disables inlining, and function calls implicitly flush memory.

Comment: I should point out that pintOS doesn't use the OPs code AFAIK. Think it is his own code. PintOS defined a `barrier()` macro that can be used in a number of different contexts. It is defined as `#define barrier() asm volatile ("" : : : "memory")` They document as _is a special statement that prevents the
compiler from making assumptions about the state of memory across the
barrier.  The compiler will not reorder reads or writes of variables
across the barrier or assume that a variable's value is unmodified
across the barrier, except for local variables whose address is never
taken._

Comment: @MichaelPetch, the code comes form PintOS indeed. Please glance  at `busy_wait` function in `timer.c`. I just made it simpler for my post.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Thanks for the correction.  I was thinking that you might have that effect indirectly, because the `asm volatile` might do something that would let it get a reference to any global from interacting with other code.  Is that anywhere near correct without `-fwhole-program` or similar?  OTOH, it's such a bad idea compared to using operands correctly that there's no need to spend a lot of effort finding special cases where it's safe to write code that hides its actions behind the compiler's back.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks a lot :).
"I forget what I've read about whether modern Intel hardware works this way or not, but I think maybe a store can retire from the out-of-order core but still not have committed to L1 cache. "  I remember that you wrote something else there. Perhaps, you didn't mean about the most modern Intel hardware. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331975/memory-ordering-two-processors in the last comment. Don't read the post because it didn't make sense I see now- it means that I make a progress :).

Comment: @PeterCordes Consider: `globalX = 1; asm("mov $6, globalX":::); globalX++;` (or see [this](https://godbolt.org/g/u7H61L)).  With or without -fwhole-program, this returns 2, not 7.  Using `memory`, `volatile` or `"+rm"(globalX)` gives the 'correct' answer.  In gcc v7.x+, basic asm does an implicit memory clobber, so I expect that to work too.  Also, *"There isn't a little demon inside the CPU"* Source?  It would sure explain a lot...

Comment: @Gilgamesz: When I wrote that previous comment, I hadn't realized that a store could retire before committing into L1.  But even an in-order CPU with no out-of-order execution can have a store buffer and thus delayed visibility of stores.  Once it's known for sure that a store *will* happen, it can retire, even if it hasn't actually happened yet and become globally visible.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Just to clarify for future readers, `volatile int globalX` yes, `asm volatile` no.  Interesting.  Obviously writing `globalX` isn't safe from an asm statement with no memory clobber, but I had the mistaken idea that reading might be.  Thanks for debunking that.  https://godbolt.org/g/d3IOyI